# ¿ Como filtrar datos de un fichero utilizando programación funcional en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando aprender programación funcional con Java, utilizando Lambdas, Streams etc, perteneciente a Java 8.

Lo que intento hacer primero es hacer un ejercicio de "programación tradicional" y después intentar usar "programación funcional" . Así de esta forma intentar ir aprendiendo ciertas funciones de la programación funcional en Java.

En este ejercicio trato filtrar los datos que tenemos en un fichero y escoger por ejemplo los registros de CO de una Provincia determinada y después hallar la media de los registros encontrados.

Tengo hecha la parte de programación tradicional, y estoy seguro que habrá muchas otras formas de hacerlo tradicionalmente , pero bueno yo lo he hecho así (por supuesto acepto vuestros consejos en este apartado también)  :)

En la parte de programación funcional aún me faltan muchos conocimientos y hay ciertas cosas que aún no sé hacer. De momento consigo filtrar los datos por una Provincia pero no se como escoger los datos de CO para luego hacer la media usando estrictamente programación funcional.

Mi código hasta ahora :

Los datos los tenemos en un fichero, este es un ejemplo:

```
Fecha;CO (mg/m3);NO (ug/m3);NO2 (ug/m3);O3 (ug/m3);PM10 (ug/m3);PM25 (ug/m3);SO2 (ug/m3);Provincia;Estación;Latitud;Longitud
31/12/2018;;2;10;49;4;;3;León;C.T.L.R. - Cuadros;42.71555555555556;-5.638888888888888
31/12/2018;;;;;29;;;León;Toral de los Vados;42.544999999999995;-6.725555555555555
31/12/2018;;2;3;59;3;3;4;Palencia;C.T.G. - Villalba;42.703611111111115;-4.827222222222222
31/12/2018;;2;5;33;;;3;León;Lario;43.04111111111111;-5.0905555555555555
31/12/2018;;65;41;5;30;23;;Valladolid;Vega Sicilia;41.620555555555555;-4.746666666666667
31/12/2018;;62;43;9;34;;5;Palencia;Palencia 3;42.019444444444446;-4.538333333333333
31/12/2018;;35;32;7;24;;5;Burgos;Miranda de Ebro2;42.68805555555555;-2.9405555555555556
31/12/2018;;76;48;;34;23;5;Valladolid;La rubia II;41.63;-4.740555555555556

public class Inicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Inicio ini = new Inicio();
        System.out.println("\n PROGRAMACION TRADICIONAL\n");
        System.out.println("La Media de CO2 de la provincia de León es : "
                + ini.hacerMedia(ini.convertirArray(ini.poblaciones(ini.leerFichero()))));

        System.out.println("\n PROGRAMACION FUNCIONAL\n");
        System.out.println("Registros de la provincia de León:\n ");
        ini.registrosLeon();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo registrosLeon lee un fichero , remueve la primera linea, filtra la
     * información escogiendo solo los registros de la pronvincia de León
     * opcionalmente podemos guardar los registros en una coleccion
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public void registrosLeon() throws IOException {
        Files.lines(Paths.get(new String("datos/cyl2.csv"))).skip(0).filter(line -> line.contains("León"))
                //.collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    /**
     * Metodo leerFichero leemos el fichero, removemos la primera linea y devolvemos
     * un nuevo array
     * 
     * @return ArrayList
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public ArrayList<String> leerFichero() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> registros = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("datos/cyl2.csv"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                registros.add(line);
            }
        }
        registros.remove(0);
        return registros;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo poblaciones buscamos las lineas que continen "León", Con substring
     * extraemos la posicion donde se encuentra el dato de Co2, Con
     * remove(String.valueOf(';') borramos los semicolon el resultado lo añadimos a
     * un nuevo array
     * 
     * @param ArrayList registros
     * @return ArrayList
     */
    public ArrayList<String> poblaciones(ArrayList<String> registros) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayCadenas = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String entrada : registros) {
            if (entrada.contains("León")) {
                arrayCadenas.add(entrada.substring(12, 13));
            }
        }
        arrayCadenas.remove(String.valueOf(';')); // Borramos el semicolon del array
        return arrayCadenas;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo convertirArray convertimos el array de string a array de integer
     * 
     * @param ArrayList <String> stringArray
     * @return ArrayList <Integer> result
     */

    public ArrayList<Integer> convertirArray(ArrayList<String> stringArray) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String stringValue : stringArray) {
            try {
                // Convertimos los Strings a Integer y los guardarmos en otro ArrayList
                result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringValue));
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo hacerMedia recibimos un ArrayList de Integer recorremos el ArrayList
     * sumando los valores y hayamos la media de Co2
     * 
     * @param arrayNumeros
     * @return int
     */
    public int hacerMedia(ArrayList<Integer> arrayNumeros) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.size(); i++) {
            sum += arrayNumeros.get(i);
            count++;
        }
        return sum / count;
    }
}


Output en Console:

 PROGRAMACION TRADICIONAL

La Media de CO2 de la provincia de León es : 3

 PROGRAMACION FUNCIONAL

31/12/2018;;2;10;49;4;;3;León;C.T.L.R. - Cuadros;42.71555555555556;-5.638888888888888
31/12/2018;;;;;29;;;León;Toral de los Vados;42.544999999999995;-6.725555555555555
31/12/2018;;2;5;33;;;3;León;Lario;43.04111111111111;-5.0905555555555555
31/12/2018;;2;10;33;10;;6;León;C.T.L.R. - Ventosilla;42.94416666666666;-5.661944444444445
31/12/2018;;9;24;10;20;;11;León;C.T.Compostilla-Cortiguera;42.611666666666665;-6.643333333333333
´´´
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando como base solo el metodo leerFichero()

```
 ArrayList<String> base=ini.leerFichero ();
```

Para aplicar filtros en java 8+ debes usar el método **filter** el cual espera una expresión Lambda(Predicate)que devuelve un resultado booleano. Si la expresión Lambda retorna verdadero, el elemento **FILTRADO** de esto se agrega a al listado resultado, caso contrario no hace nada.

```
//filtramos los elementos que contengan León
    base.stream ().filter (p -> p.contains ("León"))
```

Al haber tomado esos datos filtrados se necesita tomar los valores de CO, tal como lo has realizado, puede ser reemplazado por el método **map** el cual nos permite realizar una **TRANSFORMACIÓN** rápida de los datos y muy directa sobre el flujo original.

```
//Transformamos la lista filtrada en un nueva lista que solo contenga los datos CO
    base.stream ().filter (p -> p.contains ("León"))
                    .map (p->p.substring (12,13))
```

ahora podemos aplicar nuevamente el método **filter** para eliminar o en este caso obtener los valores diferente a ";"

```
base.stream ().filter (p -> p.contains ("Leon"))
                .map (p->p.substring (12,13))
                .filter (p ->!p.equals (";"))
```

para obtener la media ,podemos hacer uso del método average() el cual devuelve un double, no sin antes recordar que lo anterior nos devuelve un ArrayList de tipo String el cual debe ser convertido a tipo Integer, para lo cual podemos hacer uso del método **MapToInt()**

```
//con lambda
    base.stream ().filter (p -> p.contains ("Leon"))
                    .map (p->p.substring (12,13))
                    .filter (p ->!p.equals (";"))
                    .mapToInt (num->Integer.parseInt (num))


//Reference Method
   media=base.stream ()
                .filter (p -> p.contains ("Leon"))
                .map (p->p.substring (12,13))
                .filter (p ->!p.equals (";"))
                .mapToInt (Integer::parseInt)
```

finalmente unimos lo antes descrito,orElse() : devuelve el valor si está presente, de lo contrario devuelve otro

```
ArrayList<String> base=ini.leerFichero ();

        double media=base.stream ()
                .filter (p -> p.contains ("Leon"))
                .map (p->p.substring (12,13))
                .filter (p ->!p.equals (";"))
                .mapToInt (Integer::parseInt).average ().orElse (0);
```

Diferencia entre filter() y map()

El método filter devuelve un listado, al igual que el método map, La diferencia entre uno y otro es que, el método map retorna un listado del mismo tamaño, el método filter no. El método filter devuelve un listado que va desde cero a un listado que tiene como máximo el tamaño del listado de entrada. Sin embargo, a diferencia del método map, el método filter da como resultado un listado que es un sub conjunto del listado inicial.

Comment: Agradezco su buenísima explicación, me ayudo a entender un poco más la programación funcional.

Answer (score 0):

La programación funcional en Java usando streams tiene un inconveniente y es que los streams no fueron tomados del mundo teórico, es por ello que se sienten limitados para hacer algunas cosas a nuestro antojo. Comenzando desde la respuesta del buen Dramaturgo aplicada a todo, podemos mejorar el uso de memoria y evitar los bloqueos mediante programación reactiva, en este caso con [spring-webflux](/questions/tagged/spring-webflux).

El punto inicial será la conversión del código a estilo funcional:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Inicio {
    
    final URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cyl2.csv");
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {

        Inicio ini = new Inicio();
        System.out.println("\n PROGRAMACION TRADICIONAL\n");
        System.out.println("La Media de CO2 de la provincia de León es : "
                + ini.hacerMedia(ini.convertirArray(ini.poblaciones(ini.leerFichero()))));

        System.out.println("\n PROGRAMACION FUNCIONAL\n");
        System.out.println("Registros de la provincia de León:\n ");
        ini.registrosLeon();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo registrosLeon lee un fichero , remueve la primera linea, filtra la
     * información escogiendo solo los registros de la pronvincia de León
     * opcionalmente podemos guardar los registros en una coleccion
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void registrosLeon() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Path path = Path.of(new File(resource.toURI()).getAbsolutePath());
        Files.lines(path)
                .skip(0)
                .filter(line -> line.contains("León"))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    /**
     * Metodo leerFichero leemos el fichero, removemos la primera linea y
     * devolvemos un nuevo array
     *
     * @return ArrayList
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public Stream<String> leerFichero() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
        Path path = Path.of(new File(resource.toURI()).getAbsolutePath());
        return Files.lines(path)
                .skip(1);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo poblaciones buscamos las lineas que continen "León", Con substring
     * extraemos la posicion donde se encuentra el dato de Co2, Con
     * remove(String.valueOf(';') borramos los semicolon el resultado lo
     * añadimos a un nuevo array
     *
     * @param ArrayList registros
     * @return ArrayList
     */
    public Stream<String> poblaciones(Stream<String> registros) {
        return registros
                .filter(entrada-> entrada.contains("León"))
                .map(entrada-> entrada.substring(12, 13))
                .filter(p -> !p.equals(";"));
    }

    /**
     * Metodo convertirArray convertimos el array de string a array de integer
     *
     * @param ArrayList <String> stringArray
     * @return ArrayList <Integer> result
     */
    public IntStream convertirArray(Stream<String> stringArray) {
        return stringArray.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo hacerMedia recibimos un ArrayList de Integer recorremos el
     * ArrayList sumando los valores y hayamos la media de Co2
     *
     * @param arrayNumeros
     * @return int
     */
    public double hacerMedia(IntStream arrayNumeros) {
        return arrayNumeros.average().orElse(0.0d);
    }
    
}
```

para seguir usando programación funcional pero aplicando reactividad lo primero es crear un flujo a partir del archivo

```
Flux.using(
            () -> Files.lines(path), // proveedor de recursos
            Flux::fromStream, // provedor de origen
            Stream::close // limpieza de recursos
    )
```

Le agregamos las primeras dos condiciones para saltar un elemento y dejar solo los elementos que tengan *Leon* como en el caso de los streams... Y tenemos un flujo que podremos reutilizar, si esta es la gran diferencia en comparación con los streams que siempre debemos crear uno nuevo, en nuestro caso esto nos evitará tener que cargar por segunda vez el archivo en memoria.
Ahora, como no hay nada similar a IntStream como en el caso de los streams tendremos que usar un colector, afortunadamente contamos con `Collectors.averagingInt` que recibe algún método para convertir lo que tengamos a entero, en nuestro caso ya sabemos que usaremos `Integer.parseInt` que lo podemos pasar como lambda o como referencia de miembro; en lo personal prefiero las referencias de miembro debido a que no me puedo equivocar con los parámetros.

```
arrayNumeros.collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt))
```

Ahora, todos los cambios que hicimos no se ejecutarán a menos que agreguemos alguna de los dos métodos que hacen que se llame.

Uno es `subscribe` y el otro es `block`.
Block nos permite pasar de programación reactiva a modo síncrono y subscribe nos permite consumir el flujo especificando alguna función para ello (como `System.outprintln` en nuestro caso).

Quedando como

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class Inicio {

    final URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cyl2.csv");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {

        System.out.println("\n PROGRAMACION REACTIVA\n");
        Inicio ini = new Inicio();
        Flux<String> registrosLeon = ini.registrosLeon();
        System.out.println("La Media de CO2 de la provincia de León es : "
                + ini.hacerMedia(ini.poblaciones(registrosLeon)));

        System.out.println("Registros de la provincia de León:\n ");

        registrosLeon.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo registrosLeon lee un fichero , remueve la primera linea, filtra la
     * información escogiendo solo los registros de la pronvincia de León
     * opcionalmente podemos guardar los registros en una coleccion
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Flux<String> registrosLeon() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Path path = Path.of(new File(resource.toURI()).getAbsolutePath());
        return Flux.using(
                () -> Files.lines(path),
                Flux::fromStream,
                Stream::close
        ).skip(0)
                .filter(line -> line.contains("León"));
    }

    /**
     * Metodo poblaciones buscamos las lineas que continen "León", Con substring
     * extraemos la posicion donde se encuentra el dato de Co2, Con
     * remove(String.valueOf(';') borramos los semicolon el resultado lo
     * añadimos a un nuevo array
     *
     * @param ArrayList registros
     * @return ArrayList
     */
    public Flux<String> poblaciones(Flux<String> registros) {
        return registros
                .map(entrada -> entrada.substring(12, 13))
                .filter(p -> !p.equals(";"));
    }

    /**
     * Metodo hacerMedia recibimos un ArrayList de Integer recorremos el
     * ArrayList sumando los valores y hayamos la media de Co2
     *
     * @param arrayNumeros
     * @return int
     */
    public Double hacerMedia(Flux<String> arrayNumeros) {
        return arrayNumeros.collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt)).block();
    }

}
```

Configuración en maven de las dependencias:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Aun soy newbie y hasta ahora no había oído hablar de la programación reactiva en Java, estudiaré la solución propuesta. Muchísimas gracias.